# How do i convert bytes of a file into chars and show them in a textbox?

Tags: vb.net, byte

I want to import the text from the red block (see image below ) into a richtextbox in a vb.net windows forms application (the image is taken from a hex editor) is there an easy way to do this ?

[image]

I have tried to find an answer to my question using google but the examples i found there either do not work or explain how to make a complete hex editor in visual basic.

Comment: Which encoding do you want to use?  ASCII, UTF8, UTF16, ...?

Comment: Are you trying to read the EXIF tags of a jpeg by chance?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the characters are ASCII then the following should work.

```
Public Function AsciiByteToChar(ByVal b As Byte) As Char
    Dim barr() As Byte = New Byte() {b}
    Dim carr() As Char = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(barr)
    Return carr(0)
End Function
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but my main problem is importing the bytes of a file in the first place. i want my program to open the file and get all bytes and then display them in UTF8 in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ASCII encoding, just do something like this:

```
RichTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.ASCII)
```

If you want another encoding, just specify a different one.  For instance, for UTF8, use `Encoding.UTF8`.

**Side Note:**

To be technically correct, it's the hexidecimal numbers on the left that are the actual byte values.  The text on the right (in the red box) aren't the bytes--it's the ASCII representation of those bytes.

Comment: i tried this but to no avail :( , the file from which i want to get the bytes is a .jpg file if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open a [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) to the file
2. `Seek` to the first byte you want
3. `Read` the length you want
4. Use `Encoding.UTF8` (or another encoding you prefer) to convert the bytes to chars
5. Set the `Text` property of the `TextBox` to your value

   ```
   Public Sub Sample()
       Dim f As New FileStream("filepath")
       f.Seek(byteOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin)

       Dim buffer(byteLength) As Byte
       f.Read(buffer, 0, byteLength)

       Dim chars As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)
       txtBox.Text = chars
    End Sub
   ```

Comment: sorry, i am quite new to vb.net , what values do it input for byteoffset and bytelength ? i want the program to read the bytes from the first to the last

Comment: What do you mean by first to last?  If you mean the entire file, use @StevenDoggart's answer.  If you mean some portion of the file, you'll need a way to figure out what index the first byte is `byteOffset` and the last, `byteOffset + byteLength`.